# Code a probability distribution function within a range, i.e., high and lows (PYTHON)

Tags: python, distribution, exponential

I am new in Python and I have been looking how to solve the following issue. I want to code a function that will receive the inputs: minimum, maximum, scale(mean) and size for an exponential distribution.

For example:
FunctionExponentialPDF(minimum=0.05, maximum=0.30, scale=0.2, size=1000).

Result:
an exponential distribution, with a minimum value of 0.05, a maximum of 0.30, it has an average of 0.20 and it contains 1000 data points.

How can I extend the code for other probability distribution functions, e.g. normal, poisson, etc.?

Thank you all!

Comment: functionNormalPoisson(x,y,z...etc)?

Comment: what about the exponential distribution?

Comment: Exponential distributions don't work like that. You can't set a minimum, and the maximum and the scale can't be adjusted separately.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Exponential distributions work for x >= 0 . Probably I should have asked to truncate a PDF and within that range I want a minimum, maximum, scale and size.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Real-valued distributions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?#real-valued-distributions) in the `random` module, particularly `random.expovariate`.

You can make it into a generator using `yield` e.g.

```
import random

def exponential(lambd):
    while True:
        yield random.expovariate(lambd)
```

Then you can take the first 1000 using `itertools.islice`.

```
from itertools import islice

print(list(islice(exponential(1/0.3), 1000)))
```

If you want to truncate the distribution at a certain interval, you can filter it out first.

```
from itertools import filterfalse

print(list(islice(filterfalse(lambda x: not 0.05 <= x <=0.30, exponential(1/0.3)), 1000)))
```

Put it all together,

```
def FunctionExponentialPDF(minimum, maximum, scale, size):
    return islice(filterfalse(lambda x: not minimum <= x <= maximum,
                              exponential(1/scale)),
                  size)
```